# Prove it's a Tree

Tags: graph-theory

If any graph with $n$-vertices that is both connected and acyclic must have $n-1$ edges, then how does one prove that any graph with $n$-vertices, $n-1$ edges, and is acyclic must be a tree?

Comment: What is your definition of a tree?

Comment: For any two vertices there is a unique path between them.

Comment: Don't trees have to be connected, by definition?

Comment: Sure, but for any two vertices to have a unique path between them the graph must not be disjoint anyway.

Comment: @PeppersGhost oh yes the constraints do imply that don't they, oops~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We proceed by induction. Note that if $G(n,n-1)$ is acyclic, $G$ must have a vertex $v$ with degree $1$. Consider the new graph $G'=G -{v}-{e}$, where $e$ is the incident edge in $v$. So, $G'$ have $n-1$ vertices and $n-2$ edges, without cycles. Then, by induction hypotheses, $G'$ is a tree and we concluded that $G$ is a tree.

Comment: Thanks, I need to find a way to more explicitly express that at each step in our induction, G is a tree, but it should be easy to get there with this.

Comment: @PeppersGhost you're welcome. Try proof that at each step G is a tree. If you don't get it, tell me and I'll write this in my solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let the graph contain a cycle made of vertices $V_0=\{v_1,v_2,\dots, v_m\}$. This cycle also contains $m$ edges connecting the vertices. Let the set of these edges be called $E_0$

1. If $m=n$, then the graph has at least $n$ edges.
2. If $m<n$, then there exists a vertex $u$ which is connected to one of the edges in $V_0$ Add that vertex to $V_0$ and the edge connecting the vertex to $V_0$ to $E_0$ to get $E_0$ and $E_1$. Continue doing this until you get $V_k$ and $E_k$ where $|V_k|=n$. Because $|E_i|=|V_i|$ for each $i$, this means that the graph contains at least $n$ edges.

*Note*: The second part is not a rigurous answer, but can be made such by induction.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. We're discussing a graph where the number of edges is always one less than the number of vertices (n<m). Also your graph does not satisfy the definition of a tree because for any path from one vertex to another, you can take another path around the cycle in the other direction to the same vertex.

Comment: What I have proven is that if a graph has a cycle and is connected, then it has at least $n$ vertices. This means that if it has $n-1$ vertices, it must be acyclic, therefore a tree.